# Generating a follow-up time variable from age in a longitudinal data set?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have a dataset that consists of various continuous and categorical variables. I do not, however, have a follow-up time variable which I would like to create. My data set is currently in wide formate and there are 8 waves of age and 8 waves recording the event in question which is `dementia_1`. The dementia variables are binary coded as 1 and 0. How would I go about using these to variables two generate a time to event variable?

This is what the data looks like:

```
'data.frame':   18528 obs. of  1365 variables:
 $ idauniq             : int  100001 100005 100006 100007 100009 100010 100012 100016 100018 100021 ...
 $ age_1               : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ age_2               : int  52 NA NA 56 NA NA NA NA 50 54 ...
 $ age_3               : int  54 NA NA 58 66 NA 58 55 52 56 ...
 $ age_4               : int  56 NA 57 60 68 NA 60 57 NA NA ...
 $ age_5               : int  58 64 59 62 70 NA 62 NA NA 60 ...
 $ age_6               : int  NA NA 61 64 72 NA NA NA NA 62 ...
 $ age_7               : int  63 NA NA 66 74 NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ age_8               : int  NA NA NA 68 NA NA 69 NA NA NA ...
 $ sex                 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ education           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 NA 3 2 ...
 $ dementia_1          : ini  1 0 1 1 1 1 2 NA 1 NA ...
```

I would expect to have a variable that denotes the time to which it takes for each individual to have gotten dementia.

Comment: What are the meanings of various values of the dementia_1 variable? And ... can we assume there was an assessment for dementia at the first age variable that had a numeric value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you. It appears that you don't have an age recorded for each wave for each person. That being said here is an outline of an approach assuming that you only have the age after diagnosis.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate Sample Data

dat <- tibble(id = 1:50,
              age_1 = rnorm(50, 50, 2)) %>%
  mutate(
    age_2 =  age_1 + 5,
    age_3 =  age_2 + 5,
    age_4 =  age_3 + 5,
    age_5 =  age_4 + 5
  ) %>%
  add_column(dementia = rbinom(50, 1, .1))

# Now get data in long format to do the calculations
dat_2 <- dat %>% 
  gather(wave, age, contains("age"))


dat_2 %>% 
  group_by(id, dementia) %>% 
  filter(dementia==1) %>% # Diagnoses
  filter(age == min(age)) %>% 
  rename(age_at_diagnosis = age)# Age first appeared
```

This will provide you the following:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id, dementia [5]
     id dementia wave  age_at_diagnosis
  <int>    <int> <chr>            <dbl>
1     7        1 age_1             52.3
2    13        1 age_1             50.6
3    24        1 age_1             50.8
4    34        1 age_1             52.5
5    35        1 age_1             50.3
```

In theory you could then take this data frame and then join it with a deceased time, or with their minimum age in the data set.

```
first_diagnosis <- dat_2 %>% 
  group_by(id, dementia) %>% 
  filter(dementia==1) %>% # Diagnoses
  filter(age == min(age)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  rename(age_at_diagnosis = age)# Age first appeared

age_first_age <- dat_2 %>% 
  group_by(id, dementia) %>% 
  filter(age == min(age)) # Age first appeared

age_first_age %>% 
  left_join(first_diagnosis %>% 
              select(id, age_at_diagnosis), by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(time_to_event = age_at_diagnosis - age)
```

Which would give you something that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 50 x 6
# Groups:   id, dementia [50]
      id dementia wave    age age_at_diagnosis time_to_event
   <int>    <int> <chr> <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1        0 age_1  45.8             NA              NA
 2     2        0 age_1  46.7             NA              NA
 3     3        0 age_1  49.0             NA              NA
 4     4        0 age_1  53.4             NA              NA
 5     5        0 age_1  47.4             NA              NA
 6     6        0 age_1  49.1             NA              NA
 7     7        1 age_1  52.3             52.3             0
 8     8        0 age_1  49.6             NA              NA
 9     9        0 age_1  52.1             NA              NA
10    10        0 age_1  54.4             NA              NA
```